# Building a homeserver

Tags: centos, webserver, file-server

I am planning to build a homeserver to store my data. First i decided to use nas4free but later decided to use CentOS as I would also like to use it as a development server. I had 4 x 500GB hdd and I decided to use RAID10. I am planning to install minimal CentOS and use webmin so that I can remotely control the server.

Is it possible to replace the 500gb with 1 Tb one by one? I don't have much money to buy 4 1tb hdd at once.

Comment: I'm not a expert on nothing but do you need all that storage? 4 tb is kinda overkill for me o.o that's more i would need in more than 5 years

Comment: 4TB of RAID10 will give only about 2TB efective space. Actualy i need that kinda of space as i have lot of photos to store.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, you can, but by default you'll only see your capacity increase once you've installed all four 1TB drives.

The long answer is still that you can, and with some work you can see a capacity increase whenever you want. Since you're using CentOS I'll go with MD devices rather than ZFS.

(I'm going to assume you have backups here. You'll probably also want to use LVM on top of MD so that you can merge the RAID devices.)

Say your four 500GB drives are `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `sdc` and `sdd`. You create a RAID10 MD device, `/dev/md1`, and use that for storage (you can partition the devices or not, it makes no difference at this point). MD uses the smallest of the underlying devices to determine the overall capacity in this case, two times 500GB *i.e.* 1GB total.

To replace `sda` with a 1TB drive, you'd remove `sda` from the array and swap the drives. Now you have two options: either partition the new `sda`, or use the entire device. If you partition the device, create `sda1` with at least 500GB, and `sda2` with whatever's left. You can then add `sda1` to the array, and use `sda2` as-is until you get a new drive.

The second step would be to replace `sdb`; you'd proceed as above, ending up with `sdb1` in the array and `sdb2`. You can now create a RAID1 array with `sda2` and `sdb2`, which gives you a total of approximately 1.5TB with mirroring on everything.

The third step would be to replace `sdc`; you end up with `sdc2` which can be used separately from the rest.

The last step would be to replace `sdd`. Now you can simply add `sdd` to your RAID10 array, along with `sdc`; that way you can grow the array to 2GB (possibly dropping `sda1` and `sdb1` to do so). Then re-add `sdb` and `sda`, and you end up with a 2GB RAID10 array over all four drives.

There are doubtless other ways of doing this, but at least now you know it's possible...

Comment: I had similar plans. Is it any advantage in using RAID10 + LVM ? like redundancy, scalability ...

Comment: LVM separates the physical device layer from the way you manage your volumes, so it makes your life easier as an administrator (snapshots, moving volumes around, resizing them...), but it doesn't provide any more redundancy or scalability than MD. LVM does include mirroring support but last I checked its performance wasn't as good as MD's. You should still use LVM though!

Comment: I need to store mostly photos . I had backup in dvd also. So my doubt is whether i need to use MD+ lvm or MD itself?

Comment: Use MD+LVM, it's much easier to deal with especially if you're changing drive sizes.